# recv buffer not matching return bytes

Tags: sockets

is it possible for the recv socket call's buffer to not match the number of bytes returned by the call? for example:

```
const int len = 1024;
char buf[len];
int bytes = recv(socket, buf, len, 0);
```

shouldn't this always be true: `strlen(buf) = bytes`?

thanks

edit1:

i should note that i'm aware that recv can return less than the allocated size of the buffer. i'm trying to measure the amount of bytes in the buffer after the recv call. this is not a binary msg. thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`strlen` only counts up to (and not including) the first `'\0'`.  The data returned by `recv` might have several `'\0'` characters - or none at all.  So in general, it won't be true - and if it ever is, it will be by coincidence.

**Addendum:**

Even with a guaranteed "non-binary" message, `recv` and `strlen` are still counting different things.  Say you recive the string "foobar" - `recv` will put the characters `'f' 'o' 'o' 'b' 'a' 'r' '\0'` into the buffer and return 7, and calling `strlen` on the result will instead return 6.

Note also that in this situation, because `recv` can return a short value the result isn't even guaranteed to be a valid string - say `recv` decides to only give you 3 characters: then it will put `'f' 'o' 'o'` into the buffer and return 3.  Calling `strlen` on this will give an indeterminate result, because `recv` didn't write a string terminator.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like I'm still missing something...`bytes` tells you how many bytes are in the buffer (or if there was a socket error), so why bother with `strlen` or any other extra test?

You *could* test your data if 1) you know (somehow) that the data you're receiving always ends with a certain defined set of bytes; and 2) those bytes cannot possibly occur in the rest of the data, by searching the buffer for that certain set of bytes.  Absent these conditions there's no way to know...besides checking the value of `bytes`.

Answer (score 1):

strlen() expects a string, so you'll have to nul terminate the buffer before you call strlen on it.
And if you're receiving binary data, don't use strlen.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what language, what library and what the circumstances are - I'd say that it's very plausible that it doesn't wait to fill up the entire buffer until it returns.

Comment: it's c. library is winsock. strlen(buf) is called after recv returns. i don't understand how you'd compare strlen(buf) to bytes otherwise. so, your last comment doesn't make a lot of sense, but thanks.

Comment: "If no error occurs, recv returns the number of bytes received and the buffer pointed to by the buf parameter will contain this data received. If the connection has been gracefully closed, the return value is zero." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740121(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, a recv call may return fewer bytes than the size of the buffer. You shouldn't use strlen on the buffer either, since whatever bytes are sent to you may not be null terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use C.

You cannot mesure the size of a byte array with strlen

also, the recv command returns when there is nothing else to receive so it is totaly normal behavior

edit :

you don't have to count the bytes, int bytes will hold the number of bytes in the byte array

Comment: yes, i realize it's returning when there's nothing else to receive. the buffer is bigger than the expected msg. how can i measure the size of the byte array?